# How to get clientwidth binding values reactively on Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I assume clientWidth is not reactively updated.

**Problem**

I want to fit as many emails as possible in Recipients cell in one line.

In order to do so, I add an email address one at a time. If the text exceeds the width of the cell, I remove the last email added.

However, it does not update the width of the element that encloses email addresses reactively. It ends up inserting all emails regardless of the if condition.

**Attemps**

- I used "tick" method to reflect state changes that are pending since Svelte does not update the changes immediately to the DOM.

Please let me know if I am doing things wrong or any solution. Thank you!

[image: client-width-not-updated]

```
<script>
    import { tick } from 'svelte';
    let recipients = ["aaaa@dsad.com", "djdosa@dsoad.com", "dksoadk@.com", "kofksodpofds@dsad.com"];
    let recipientDisplayList = [];

    let innerWidth = 0;
    let recipientsWidth = 0;

    $: {
        if(innerWidth) {
            setRecipientDisplayList();
        }
    }

    async function setRecipientDisplayList() {
        for(let i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            recipientDisplayList.push(recipients[i]);
            recipientDisplayList = recipientDisplayList; // https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects
            await tick(); // wait for pending state changes to be reflected
            console.log(recipients[i])
            if(recipientsWidth > innerWidth) {
                recipientDisplayList.pop();
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    th, td, table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #333333;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
        max-width: 300px;
        min-width: 100px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .recipients {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Sender</th>
            <th>Recipients</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kouta Nakano</td>
            <td>
                <div bind:clientWidth={innerWidth}>
                    <span bind:clientWidth={recipientsWidth} class="recipients">
                        {#each recipientDisplayList as recipient}
                        {recipient},&nbsp
                        {/each}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you I would expect `recipientsWidth` to update after the `await tick()` and can't say why it behaves differently

When wrapping every email address in its own span with the width bind to `recipientsWidth` and keep track of the sum of the spans and the relation to the container div, it would work [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6f005d33367643b4a9a6757482721f0d?version=3.46.2)
But why not use [`text-overflow: ellipsis;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) instead, so
it's visible that there are more mail addresses?

```
<script>
    import { onMount, tick } from 'svelte';
    let recipients = ["aaaa@dsad.com", "djdosa@dsoad.com", "dksoadk@.com", "kofksodpofds@dsad.com"];
    let recipientDisplayList = [];

    let innerWidth = 0;
    let recipientsWidth = 0;
    let recipentsWidthSum = 0;

    onMount(async () => {
        for(let recipient of recipients) {
            recipientDisplayList = [...recipientDisplayList, recipient]
            await tick()
            recipentsWidthSum += recipientsWidth
            if(recipentsWidthSum > innerWidth) {
                recipientDisplayList.pop()
                recipientDisplayList = recipientDisplayList
                break;
            }
        }
    })
</script>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Sender</th>
            <th>Recipients</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kouta Nakano</td>
            <td>
                <div class="client" bind:clientWidth={innerWidth}>
                    {#each recipientDisplayList as recipient, index}
                    <span bind:clientWidth={recipientsWidth} class="recipient">
                        {recipient},&nbsp
                    </span>
                    {/each}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<style>
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    th, td, table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #333333;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
        max-width: 300px;
        min-width: 100px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .client {
        border: 1px solid teal;
    }
    .recipient {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid magenta;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: know right? ellipsis the whole thing would be so much easier 

I will try that after gym. Thanks

Comment: so as the window size changes, I want the cell to be updated with more or less emails. So probably I need to use $: function rather than onMount. Also, there gonna be 40 rows of data. I feel like it's even more expensive computation than keeping track of the whole collection of email texts.

Comment: Right, if this should be recalculated when the width changes, the reactive statement $: is the way to go